# to reverse the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, reverse

Here is my code to reverse the elements in an array:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt(); 
        }
        int i=0;
        int j=n-1;
        int c;
        while(i<j){
            c=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=c;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[n]);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is my code is generating `arrayIndexOutOfBound` exception. How to remove it ?

Comment: Please include sample input that causes this exception.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 1):

Change,

```
System.out.println(arr[n]);
```

to:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(arr[n]);
Here is the problem because there's no index "n" 
n is the number of elements
You have to loop form 0 to n-1

```
    for(int i =0;i < n;i++){
System.out.println(arr[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine for reversing the array of elements but arrayIndexOutOfBound exception is raised due to System.out.println(arr[n]). Remember array index starts from zero.For n size array, the range will be [0,(n-1)] ie., if n=5 range will be 0 to 4.

```
for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++)
{ 
   System.out.println(arr[k]);
}
```